# How to check if a List Argument is None

Tags: python, algorithm

I am doing this problem set, and I cannot get passed the Test Case for when the List is None.

I have tested for almost all the cases, and I have noticed that other users got it right with a code that is very similar to mine, I need help debugging and checking if I am missing a test case in my Conditionals.

The test cases that come back negative are testing to see if the List is None, which I found out by testing in the Python interpreter that it does not necessarily imply empty.

Here is the Code:

```
def likes(names):

    for i in names:

        if not names:
            return "no one likes this"
        elif len(names) <= 0:
            return "no one likes this"
        elif len(names) == 1:
            text = "{} likes this"
            return text.format(names[0])
        elif names == None:
            return "no one likes this"
        elif len(names) > 2 and len(names) <= 4 and len(names) != 3:
            additional = len(names) - 2
            text = "{}, {} and {} others like this"
            return text.format(names[0], names[1], additional)
        elif len(names) > 2 and len(names) > 4 and len(names) != 3:
            additional = len(names) - 2
            text = "{}, {} and {} others like this"
            return text.format(names[0], names[1], additional)
        elif len(names) == 2:
            text = "{} and {} like this"
            return text.format(names[0], names[1])
        elif len(names) == 3:
            text = "{}, {} and {} like this"
            return text.format(names[0], names[1], names[2])
        else:
            text = "{} likes this"
            return text.format(names[0])
```

Comment: You need to check for `None` before the loop, because it's an error to iterate over `None`.

Comment: In fact, why is the `for i in names` loop even there?  It serves no purpose that I can see.  You never use the loop variable `i`, and all the possible branches exit the function immediately, so the loop never runs more than once.

Comment: Also, don't use if *names == None*. it should be *if names is None*.

Comment: @JohnGordon Furthermore, if `names` is `None` or an empty list the loop **never** executes and `None` will be implicitly returned

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes the loop does execute (or attempts to), because the `for` statement is the very first line of code in the function.  The check `if not names` is _inside_ the loop.

Comment: @JohnGordon If `names` is `None` then an exception is raised. If `names` is an empty list, the loop will not execute even once. check it.

Comment: @mkam is refers to the object being in the same memory location as None, like an alias, it doesn't work, actually failed some of the cases I passed

Comment: @JohnGordon it worked, I only needed to take the conditionals out of the loop, cancelled the loop and it worked perfectly

Comment: It's a good reminder that list_var = [] is not the same as iter(list_var)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JohnGordon, I only needed to remove the for loop around the conditionals, it works just fine

```
def likes(names):
    if not names:
        return "no one likes this"
    elif len(names) <= 0:
        return "no one likes this"
    elif len(names) == 1:
        text = "{} likes this"
        return text.format(names[0])
    elif names == None:
        return "no one likes this"
    elif len(names) > 2 and len(names) <= 4 and len(names) != 3:
        additional = len(names) - 2
        text = "{}, {} and {} others like this"
        return text.format(names[0], names[1], additional)
    elif len(names) > 2 and len(names) > 4 and len(names) != 3:
        additional = len(names) - 2
        text = "{}, {} and {} others like this"
        return text.format(names[0], names[1], additional)
    elif len(names) == 2:
        text = "{} and {} like this"
        return text.format(names[0], names[1])
    elif len(names) == 3:
        text = "{}, {} and {} like this"
        return text.format(names[0], names[1], names[2])
    else:
        text = "{} likes this"
        return text.format(names[0])
```

Comment: It may work, but the logic is as confused as ever. Take a good, long look at the analysis and solution courtesy of @ggorlen.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do with the `for i in names:` line in your code. I assume you are trying to iterate through the list of `names`. If this is the case, I would change the line to `for name in names:`.

Keep in mind that `list = None` is different from `list = []`. When `list = None`, list is undefined. On the other hand, `list = []` signifies an empty list.

Here is an example that may be helpful.

```
def checkListVal(valList):
# Checks to see if valList stores some data
if valList == None:
    print("valList is undefined")
    # Returns out of this function
    return

# Checks to see if the list is empty
if len(valList) == 0:
    print("valList is empty")
    return

for val in valList:
    if val == "val1":
        print("val1 in valList")
    elif val == "val2":
        print("val2 in valList")
    else:
        print("val equals " + val)

valList1 = ["val1", "val2", "val3"]
valList2 = []
valList3 = None

checkListVal(valList1)
print()

checkListVal(valList2)
print()

checkListVal(valList3)
```

The output is as follows:

```
val1 in valList
val2 in valList
val equals val3

valList is empty

valList is undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that if `None` is a possible argument, the `for` loop will crash. As mentioned in the comments, this loop isn't relevant to the logic anyway because it simply returns on the first iteration. We're only interested in properties about the length of the list (if it exists), not its elements, so remove the loop.

Having said that, the logic here is extremely confusing and there are many redundant branches. Conditionals that have more than 3 or 4 branches or nesting greater than a couple levels are difficult to reason about and should be eliminated.

- The branch

  ```
  elif len(names) > 2 and len(names) > 4 and len(names) != 3:
  ```

  can be simplified to `elif len(names) > 4` because if `len(names)` is greater than 4, we know for sure it's definitely `!= 3` and `> 2`.
- The branch `if not names:` covers cases `names is None` as well as `len(names) <= 0` (the `<` is unnecessary here), so we can toss out two more branches.
- The branch

  ```
  elif len(names) > 2 and len(names) <= 4 and len(names) != 3:
  ```

  is the same as `elif len(names) == 4`.

Taking a step back, there are only 5 cases:

1. we have no names
2. we have 1 name
3. we have 2 names
4. we have 3 names
5. we have 4 or more names

Here's a re-write to express this clearly:

```
def likes(names):
    if not names:
        return "no one likes this"
    elif len(names) == 1:
        return f"{names[0]} likes this"
    elif len(names) == 2:
        return f"{names[0]} and {names[1]} like this"
    elif len(names) == 3:
        return f"{names[0]}, {names[1]} and {names[2]} like this"

    return f"{names[0]}, {names[1]} and {len(names) - 2} others like this"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    names = ["alice", "bob", "carol", "doug", "eric", "fred"]
    print("None =>", likes(None))

    for i in range(len(names)):
        print(names[:i], "=>", likes(names[:i]))
```

Output:

```
None => no one likes this
[] => no one likes this
['alice'] => alice likes this
['alice', 'bob'] => alice and bob like this
['alice', 'bob', 'carol'] => alice, bob and carol like this
['alice', 'bob', 'carol', 'doug'] => alice, bob and 2 others like this
['alice', 'bob', 'carol', 'doug', 'eric'] => alice, bob and 3 others like this
```